# Access localhost SQL Server Express from within docker container running in docker-desktop

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, sql-server-express

My DB connection string uses this: `Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;` to point to the DB,
this works when running the project diectly but not when running it inside docker locally using docker-desktop.

I tried using `Data Source=localhost,1433;` and mapping the port `1433:1433` in compose.yaml, but it didn't help, also I was looking in `TCPView`, didn't see SQL listening to `1433` or any other port.

Has anyone ever managed to connect to the localhost sqlexpress from inside docker container running also on localost?

Comment: Docker containers are essentially their own little Linux VMs, so from a networking point of view `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `::1` all reference the container itself. If you need to access services exposed or installed on the host, have you tried the special `host.docker.internal` name?

Comment: [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) discusses this at length; application in a container, database not in a container but on the same host (so two separate meanings of `localhost`).  Does one of the techniques there help you?

Comment: I'm getting: `A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Success)` when using `Data Source=host.docker.internal,1433` in my connection string